# Why am I unable to successfully export a path within a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, path

In order to get some C code to compile correctly, I need to export a folder so that are certain file is found.

On the command line, if I first run

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/bin/path../version/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

and then the executable from the C code works. If I do not export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, then the executable will fail, as the C package cannot find the necessary file, i.e.

```
exectuable: error while loading shared libraries: file1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I would now like to run this code via a bash script. Here is my bash script, `run_stuff.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/.bash_profile

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/bin/path../version/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

path/to/executable/executable
```

This fails, with the error above. I have since tried

`echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/bin/path../version/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`

within the bash script, and I have added

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/bin/path../version/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

within `~/.bash_profile`. It still doesn't work---the C code cannot find this file.

How does one correctly export a folder within a bash script?

Comment: I would recommend wrapping that export in quotes: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/bin/path../version/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`, it's possible the variable setting is choking because it's not sure where the start/end is, would depend on the rest of the contents of your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1

It can be exported locally.

```
#!/bin/bash

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/bin/path../version/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH path/to/executable/executable
```

using `VAR=value cmd` will set and export VAR for `cmd` process.

### 2

export it in two step

```
#!/bin/bash

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/bin/path../version/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

path/to/executable/executable
```

this is the way I do in my scripts. (note that this contradict what man page says)

> export [-fn] [name[=word]] ...
>
> If a variable name is followed by =word, the value of the variable is set to word.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this now. I'm still a bit confused why placing the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before the executable without `export` changes things. Could you elaborate somewhat?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang Variables can be set in the same line as a command in bash, in which case the variable is only set/changed for that command. It's perhaps a bit more explicit, though it shouldn't function any differently.

Comment: Just tried this approach. I'm getting the same error as before...

Comment: @Centimane Even `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/bin/path../version/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` was a total failure

Comment: @ShanZhengYang What do you get if you `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` after exporting it?

Comment: @Centimane I've also tried adding `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/bin/path../version/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` within `~/.bash_profile`. So, `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` does give back `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/bin/path../version/`

Comment: @ShanZhengYang Wait, when you echo it it lists the "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=" before the paths?! That won't be parsed properly by things looking for shared objects. Not sure how you got into the variable though.

Comment: @Centimane Sorry, cannot edit---that's a typo. It only gives back `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/bin/path../version/`